# Problema con controllers de MVC .NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, mvc, controller, net

soy nuevo en .NET MVC quería saber si me podrían ayudar. Estoy trabajando con un pequeño proyecto creado en .NET MVC. Me pidieron hacer modificaciones, sin embargo el proyecto no me permite hacerlas pues al realizar cambios en los controladores, sea para agregar o quitar funciones al ejecutar no realiza los cambios, muestra como si nada hubiese cambiado, no importa que agregue. Incluso he eliminado el archivo del controlador y no ha pasado nada, sigue mostrando la información. En cambio si realizo una modificación en alguna vista si se ve reflejada al ejecutar el proyecto. Ya intenté limpiar la solución y recompilar y no funciona, quisiera saber de donde está jalando los archivos.

Tengo los siguientes errores en el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, tengo comentadas algunas lineas de código en un controlador llamado Articulo, específicamente en la función Detalle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente al guardar y ejecutar me sigue mostrando la información a pesar de haber cortado el return de la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Jorge. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir el código con lo que has intentado? De esta forma si te arroja algún error (que también deberías agregarlo a tu pregunta) o tienes alguna incertidumbre la comunidad puede ayudarte y no se cierra la pregunta. Te animo a leer el siguiente enlace de cómo preguntar: [es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] Saludos.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y dale una visita a este workshop que hice tiempo atrás, te será de ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY es un super comprimido de 4 horas 4 minutos y 4 segundos de lo necesario para explorar el panorama de ASPnet MVC :D

Comment: Acabo de revisar la actualización que has hecho, ¿cómo es que puedes ejecutar si el build process está roto? ¿Tienes hosteado la aplicación en un IIS Local?

Comment: No, he cambiado la opción del apartado "Servidores" y he seleccionado la opción "Usar servidor de desarrollo de Visual Studio", ya que la opción del servidor web IIS  local me daba el error 'SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG'